# Populating a cell in datagridview using conditional statement

Tags: c#, datagridview, conditional-statements

I have a datagrid that is populated with data taken from variables. These include a test score and an average time value. I want to automatically populate one of the columns based upon what the data is in the other columns.

I have tried to put together a conditional statement as shown in the code but it column 5 is still appearing blank.

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                        {
                            if (time > 20)
                            {
                                row.Cells[5].Value = "Beginner";
                            }
                            else if (time < 20 )
                            {
                                row.Cells[5].Value = "Intermediate";
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: What is the value of time variable?

Comment: The time is taken from 5 integer inputs and is the average of these 5 times.

Comment: Did you try to debug, like put a breakpoint inside the loop and see the actual flow?

Comment: Just tried it - didn't really help. Thanks.